# How to combine a local editor with a remote compiler?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, g++, local

I am used to the local IDE interface which integrates the code editor and compiler. However, I want to test if the code compiles well with the remote compiler on Unix server. I am tired of copying my source file to the server, and working in the command window (SSH shell). What I expect is to do some configuration in the programming software (Xcode, Eclipse, Visual Studio), specify compiling with the compiler located at remote server. Is there a way to change the local default compiler with a remote compiler (remote GNU compiler, gcc/g++)?

Comment: ive been really wanting to start a project that would enable mobile development (basically an ide for android or ios)  getting an answer to this though could make that project alot simpler. (+1)

Comment: @owen gerig -- Good idea! It might be that all you really want to do is hide or automate: 1. the ftp of the source file up to the isp; 2. run gcc on that file (shell script); and 3. ftp gcc errors/warnings back down. Is that too simplistic?

Comment: no i dont think so, there will be alot more latency in the process but considering that its enabling something to be done that currently isnt available is a decent trade off

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle Studio](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18659_01/html/821-2125/studioidetut.html#gkckf) allows one to do exactly that. With remote Linux or Solaris.

Comment: Now, i've found an remote system plugin of Eclipse can exactly do this. http://www.eclipse.org/tm/